# SQL group records with same value, and place that into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to group same record with SQL, the following is my result

```
Name  Code   Qty
data1  AG   12
data1  AS   15
data2  MS   10
data2  IS   11
```

I want it to be like this instead.

```
Name  Code   Qty Code  Qty
data1  AG    12   AS   15
data2  MS    10   IS   11
```

Can this be done in SQL only?

Comment: what would you do if there were three records under the same `Name`?

Comment: same thing except there will be three different code instead of two and so on.

Comment: Are you trying to list horizontally different rows by group by? Give scenario if data1 has 7-8 different rows and data2 has 1-2 records.

Comment: @JohnDoe4136: Are you using SQLServer?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SQLServer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can this be done in SQL only?

With a variable number of columns you have to build a the query dynamically.
I would hardly call this "SQL only" but it can be done in T-SQL and here is one way.

```
-- Sample table
declare @T table
(
  Name varchar(5),
  Code varchar(2),
  Qty int
)

-- Sample data
insert into @T values
('data1',  'AG',   12),
('data1',  'AS',   15),
('data1',  'AQ',   17),
('data2',  'MS',   10),
('data2',  'IS',   11)

declare @XML xml
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
declare @Max int

-- Max number of codes per name
select @Max = max(C)
from (select count(*) as C
      from @T
      group by Name) as T

-- Convert table to XML
set @XML = (select Name,
                   (select Code,
                           Qty
                    from @T as T2
                    where T1.Name = T2.Name
                    for xml path('c'), type)
            from @T as T1
            group by Name
            for xml path('r'))

-- Build a dynamic query
;with Numbers(Number) as 
(
  select 1
  union all
  select Number + 1
  from Numbers
  where Number < @Max
)
select @SQL = 'select T.N.value(''Name[1]'', ''varchar(5)'') as Name ' +
               (select ',T.N.value(''c['+cast(Number as nvarchar(10))+']/Code[1]'', ''char(2)'') as Code
                        ,T.N.value(''c['+cast(Number as nvarchar(10))+']/Qty[1]'', ''int'') as Qty'
                from Numbers
                for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') +
              ' from @xml.nodes(''/r'') as T(N)'

-- Execute query
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@xml xml', @XML
```

Result:

```
Name  Code Qty         Code Qty         Code Qty
----- ---- ----------- ---- ----------- ---- -----------
data1 AG   12          AS   15          AQ   17
data2 MS   10          IS   11          NULL NULL
```

Try here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/122860/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQLServer, you could use rank to assign a sequential number to each code with the name group, like so:

```
select Name, Code, Qty, Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Code) AS CodeRank
from MyTable
```

Then you can use the pivot functionality within either SQLServer or SSRS to format this as required.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. You can hack around with the idea of concatenating lots of Code,Qty pairs into a single value for each record, though. I'm not sure what you're planning to do with multiple columns with the same name, even if such a thing were possible.

Comment: that's another question :) - but generally, you still will need to work around the issue of having multiple columns with the same name, and a dynamic number of columns.